# CosmosDb - Determining best partitionKey when only fetching data by their Id

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I’ve been dabbling with CosmosDb and am now starting to get in the range of over 10k documents instead of just a few.

I’m struggling with how best to partition.

Some background
•   I will have 10-50k documents in CosmosDb (maybe more in later phases)
•   I have an index on top of those in Azure Search, for a small subset of these document’s properties)
•   I will NOT be performing complex searches in CosmosDb
  except:
•   I will be fetching documents from cosmosDb by their Id  (most likely coming from Azure Search results, when the user clicks one of the results)
o   Initially only 1 document will be requested
o   Possibly, in the future, I might ask for e.g. 10 documents at the same time, all by their Id.

I currently have 1 partition, which feels like a waste of a good system.
I could partition on e.g. the last digit of the document number, which would give a nice spread of documents across 10 partitions.

My concrete question:
If I spread data equally (almost randomly, to be honest) across 10 partitions, does that speed up fetching documents by Id (assuming many simultaneous calls to the system, each fetching 1 document by Id).

My reasoning: The last digit would determine the partition, so only 1 partition would be accessed to find the document, which is better than searching all partitions at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Spreading data across partitions does not make things faster on the read path in a partitioned data store. Where it helps is on the write path because you are spreading the load out horizontally across many computers simultaneously. And this only matters where the amount of throughput overloads what a single partition can achieve. For Cosmos DB this is 10,000 RU.

The key to fast reads is to indicate the partition key value in your read. The partition key is basically a router to where your data is stored. Once there it uses the index (or id in your case) to find the data.

There's some articles that provide some details on partitioning that are helpful.

[Partitioning in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview)

[How to model and partition data on Azure Cosmos DB using a real-world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

Hope this helps.